# String.Join() with string interpolation for string array in C#

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I had an issue on using string interpolation in string.join

```
    string type1 = "a,b,c";
    string[] type2 = new string[3] { "a", "b", "c" };
```

how to write the string.Join query, below code is just my attempt, but the result is not as expected.

```
    string result = string.Join(",", $"'{type1}'");
```

**In both cases, the output should be 'a','b','c'**

how to use string.Join() with string interpolation for an array of strings

Comment: @41686d6564 well, technically a string **is** an enumerable. However I doubt that´s what OP wants.

Comment: `var bob = string.Join(",", type2.Select(z => $"'{z}'"));` https://dotnetfiddle.net/wKYbz8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add single quotes around each elements, you can apply a simple `.Select()` sequence, such as :

```
var type1 = "a,b,c";
var type2 = new string[3] { "a", "b", "c" };

// using System.Linq;
var result1 = string.Join(',', type1.Split(',').Select(x => $"'{x}'"));
var result2 = string.Join(',', type2.Select(x => $"'{x}'"));

Console.WriteLine($"Type1 : {result1}");
Console.WriteLine($"Type2 : {result2}");
```

This outputs :

```
Type1 : 'a','b','c'
Type2 : 'a','b','c'
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AdBFce)

Comment: Yep, based on the OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63372092/string-join-with-string-interpolation-for-string-array-in-c-sharp#comment112058421_63372126) to the other answer, it looks like that's what they want.

Comment: Well, even based on OP's question